# Exisiting Windows Server 2008 R2 does not see new SSD

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, hard-drive, hardware-raid

O/S: Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise Service Pack 1 64-bit

*PER IBM Integrated Management Module II:*

**IBM ServerRAID M5110e SCSI Disk Device**

- Drive 0 - 931.513GB
- Drive 1 - 931.513GB (Mirror)
- Drive 3 - 447.132GB (new SSD)

The system has been running for a few years, updated firmware and drivers for raid controller and drives.

- Update controller driver to 6.710.15.00
- Update Imm firmware to latest 1A0072H
- Update Uefi firmware to latest VVE150C

The Bios and Raid controller sees all hard drives (existing drives and new SSD drive), but the O/S does not show the new SSD drive anywhere.

---

What is even stranger is i added the same hard drive to two servers, they are exactly the same hardware, same firmware. But the one runs Windows Server 2012 and that one picked up the new SSD without any problems.

Comment: I don't know much about IBM hardware, but many RAID controllers need you to create a volume on a disk to make it visible on the host.

Comment: As far as i know the new SSD is: MZ7LM480HCHP (PM863) - SAMSUNG 480 GB Serial ATA 6.0 Gbps 2.5 inch

Answer (score 1):

The LSI RAID controller does not pass the disk through per default. You have to create a *virtual disk* in the controller, using your new disk, which is then seen by the OS. If the other server picked up the SSD directly, maybe you have the controller in IT mode? Although you would need to reflash the controller for that to work.